# Decompose compound words

Tags: search, lucene

I'm using  Lucene 4.10.4

I would like that if a document contains the word **cheeseburger** and the search for **cheese burger** or  **cheese** or  **burger** should bring this document. 
I tried **DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter**. And the words to match against is passed as word dictionary externally.

Is there any way to match against the indexed words and to do the above in more efficient way than the **DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter**

Comment: So, is the problem that it uses a brute-force algorithm (if so, why is this a problem?), or that you have to provide the dictionary?

Comment: Providing dictionary is my problem. I want to match against the indexed words.

Comment: how you want to split them? i mean how algorithm should understand that cheese and burger are separate words?

Comment: If **cheese** and **burger** are indexed and if I search for **cheeseburger**, I want the document containing **cheese** and **burger**. **DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilter** matches against the words in the dictionary file but I want to match against the indexed words.